# Magento 2.4.5 Google Analytics

Tags: magento2, google-analytics-4

have someone experience with Google Analytics 4 on Magento 2.4.5 (integration with default Magento GTag)?
Works it well?
Is there 100% order accuracy between Magento and Google Analytics?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I use the Weltpixel module ( https://www.weltpixel.com/google-analytics-4-ga4-with-gtm-support-for-magento-2.html ) for Magento integration with Google Analytics, the module is already adapted to the GA4 model and it's a great solution and so far I haven't had any problems.

Comment: Which version of that module (basic or pro)?

Comment: I use the pro version of the module, however the free version is also a good option with less features

Answer (score -1):

You can also give this free extension a try - https://croapp.com/free-google-analytics-4-integration-magento-2-plugin/